# How to use a counting function and case_when simultaneously in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, case-when, summarize

I have a dataframe, and I want to count the number of observations for each name that meet a certain criteria:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley", "Justin", "Corey", "Sibley", "Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
               class = c("Bio", "Bio", "Bio", "Psych", "Pysch", "Psych", "English", "English", "English"),
               result = c("Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass", "Pass", "Fail", "Fail", "Pass"))
```

In the above example, the courses the students took are either STEM (e.g., "Bio" & "Psych") or literature ("English"). I want to make two new columns, one that says their STEM score, and one that contains their literature score, where the code will count 1 for each pass.

The answer should look like:

```
library(dplyr)
answer <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                 stem_assessment = c(0, 2, 2),
                 lit_assessment = c(0, 0, 1))
```

I've tried experimenting with `case_when()`, `group_by()`, `n()`, `summarize()`, and `count()`, but I can't seem to crack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` and `summarise` should do -

```
library(dplyr)

stem <- c("Bio", "Pysch", "Psych")
lit <- c('English')

test %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(stem_assessment = sum(class %in% stem & result == "Pass"),
            lit_assessment = sum(class %in% lit & result == "Pass"))

#   name   stem_assessment lit_assessment
#  <chr>            <int>          <int>
#1 Corey                2              0
#2 Justin               0              0
#3 Sibley               2              1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `count()` and `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`. I also coded the typo (Pysch) in `test`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  mutate(
    stem_assessment = class %in% c("Bio", "Psych", "Pysch") & result == "Pass",
    lit_assessment = class == "English" & result == "Pass"
  ) %>% 
  select(-c(class, result)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>% 
  count(name, var, wt = value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = var, values_from = n)
```

Comment: thanks! Also, for anyone reading this, to use pivot_longer() or pivot_wider(), you need to load in the tidyr package.

Comment: Good point! Thanks. I added the code for loading `tidyverse`.